# vba excel userform.show not working

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, userform

I'm a bit new to VBA, and I think I have a basic understanding of how to use it. My User Form is running fine, but under a very specific condition that I don't like. It can only draw the checkboxes if and only if I run the main code first, and even then it only works the first time and won't update with respect to changes in the workbook. I assumed it was due to needing the public variable to be run, but after testing that theory, the problem persist. Can anyone help me solve this problem? What is causing this?

Here is my main Code:

```
Public Allplans As Integer

Sub Compare()

    Allplans = Sheets.Count - 2
    UF1.Show

''''Clear old series
For Each Series In Sheets(2).SeriesCollection
        Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Next

''''Add new series
For i = 1 To Allplans
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(i).Name = Sheets(i + 2).Range("$A$1")
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Sheets(i + 2).Range("$A$10:$A$23")
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets(i + 2).Range("$B$10:$B$23")
Next

End Sub
```

And this is my User Form:

```
Private Sub UF1_Initialize()

Dim i           As Integer
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

For i = 1 To Allplans
    Set chkBox = UF1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = Sheets(i + 2).Name
    chkBox.Left = 10
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
    chkBox.Value = True
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `UF1_Initialize`? If this is the initialize event the name is UserForm_Initialize regardless what the name of the form is. Do you really use the name of the form inside the code of the form:  `Set chkBox = UF1.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & i)`? Don't do that! You also don't really need a global variable, but that is another story. And the last point: Do not use the [default instance](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) of the userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not give that much information please try the following changes to your code. Rename `UF1_Initialize` to `UserForm_Initializ`and use the `Me`key word in it like that

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i           As Integer
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

For i = 1 To Allplans
    Set chkBox = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = Sheets(i + 2).Name
    chkBox.Left = 10
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
    chkBox.Value = True
Next

End Sub
```

Also do not use the [default instance](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) of the userform

```
Option Explicit

Public Allplans As Integer

Sub Compare()

Dim series
Dim i As Long

    Allplans = Sheets.Count - 2

    Dim myUF1 As New UF1
    myUF1.Show

''''Clear old series
For Each series In Sheets(2).SeriesCollection
        Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Next

''''Add new series
For i = 1 To Allplans
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(i).Name = Sheets(i + 2).Range("$A$1")
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Sheets(i + 2).Range("$A$10:$A$23")
    Sheets(2).SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets(i + 2).Range("$B$10:$B$23")
Next

End Sub
```

It is also [good practise](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/train-users-to-follow-best-practices-when-writing-vba-code/) to use `Option Explicit`, just please also have a look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#Is_Dim_Actually_Required). You might also have a look at [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/) tutorial, especially the part to add code for [cancelling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/#Cancelling_the_UserForm) the form

Comment: Ok, I went back and did some more research on default instance, as that was the most confusing thing you mentioned. [This site](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html) did a wonderful job of explaining the concept for me and it helped me fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your form only initialises the once, hence the code only runs the first time. Consider under what circumstances you want to change the form, and then trigger your code at that time. This means taking the code out from the `UF1_Initialize` handler and running it under some other event handler in the form.

Not enough context or information in your question to provide anything more concrete than this!